# Add a view dynamically to the item of the RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to add the extra `TextView` to the item of the `RecyclerView.Adapter` based on the ModalObject sent to the `RecyclerView.Adapter`

**Example**:

I had a modal object with `isAddText` variable. In `onCreateViewHolder` will create the Holder Object with sending the `itemView` as an parameter.

```
@Override
public SolventViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.solvent_list, null);
    SolventViewHolders rcv = new SolventViewHolders(layoutView);
    return rcv;
}
```

SolventViewHolders.java

```
public SolventViewHolders(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
    imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_photo);
    //  Now i need add a view to the itemView parent based on ModalObject isAddView property and how to do that. 
}
```

Comment: You can add textview in layout, and based on your condition make it visible/invisible.

Comment: I dont want to so..because it contain more views and dependencies

Answer (score 35):

## The problem

Normally, you would need to execute itemView.addView(view, layoutParams) to add another view programatically to your layout, but thing with ViewHolders is, they will be reused by RecyclerView to bind different items from the adapter, so you can't do that or this new TextView you wish to add will appear when another item is bound to this viewHolder instance again.

I can think of a few ways you can achieve your goal:

---

## 1. Switch the View's visibility

The first way is to add this textView to your layout and have its visibility by GONE by default, and set it to VISIBLE when binding that one item you need this TextView for, such as:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AbstractViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.extraTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if(shouldShowExtraTextView) {
        holder.extraTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.extraTextView.setText(/* your text */);
    }
    // proceed to bind item to holder
}
```

---

## 2. Implement different ViewHolders

The second way is more elegant, it involves creating different ViewHolder type. First you need to create int constants for the two types of view to be shown by RecyclerView. Place in your adapter the following code:

```
private static final int VIEW_ORDINARY = 0;
private static final int VIEW_WITH_EXTRA_TEXT_VIEW = 1;
```

Then implement the getItemViewType(int position) method of the adapter:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(position == /* position of item that needs extra text view */) {
        return VIEW_WITH_EXTRA_TEXT_VIEW;
    } else {
        return VIEW_ORDINARY;
    }
}
```

Next step is to create different Holder depending on returned type:

```
@Override
public SolventViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if(viewType == VIEW_WITH_EXTRA_TEXT_VIEW) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                                      .inflate(R.layout.solvent_list_with_extra_text_view, parent, false);
        return new SolventViewHolderWithExtraTextView(itemView);
    } else {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                                      .inflate(R.layout.solvent_list, parent, false);
        return new SolventViewHolder(itemView);
    }
}
```

Of course you need to define SolventViewHolderWithExtraTextView:

```
class SolventViewHolderWithExtraTextView extends SolventViewHolder {
    TextView extraTextView;

    public SolventViewHolderWithExtraTextView(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.extraTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.extra_text_view);
    }
}
```

And then in onBindViewHolder():

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SolventViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // you can use inheritance to handle binding logic or check the item view type again:
    // bind ordinary view
    if(getItemViewType(position)) {
        // bind the extra textView
        ((SolventViewHolderWithExtraTextView)holder).extraTextView.setText("I hope this works");
    }
}
```

This way you have another type of ViewHolder for your items that need another TextView, and it will be reused within that category. It's a preferred way to do what you want to.

---

## 3. Add/remove View dynamically

Another answer (which is really ugly solution if you ask me) is to add and remove view dynamically, such as:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AbstractViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(shouldDisplayExtraTextView) {
        if(!holder.displaysExtraTextView() {
            holder.addExtraTextView();
        }
        holder.extraTextView.setText("This solution is really ugly");
        } else {
        if(holder.displaysExtraTextView() {
            holder.removeExtraTextView();
        }
    }
}

class SolventViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView extraTextView;
    boolean viewAdded = false;

    public SolventViewHolders(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_photo);
         //  Now i need add a view to the itemView parent based on ModalObject isAddView property and how to do that. 

        extraTextView = new TextView();
}

public void addExtraTextView() {
    ((ViewGroup)itemView).addView(extraTextView, layoutParams);
    viewAdded = true;
}

public void removeExtraTextView() {
    ((ViewGroup)itemView).removeView(extraTextView);
    viewAdded = false;
}

public boolean displaysExtraTextView() {
    return viewAdded;
}
```

This is really ugly, because to add view to itemView you need to cast it to ViewGroup (which it doesn't have to be), so ensure that it always will be a ViewGroup or its subclass. Also, you need to provide proper layoutParams to add the extraTextView to itemView.

Comment: I dont want to inflate the layouts, the only way for me to add the views dynamically.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include another way you can achieve what you want, though it's really not an elegant solution, but if for some reason, as you say, you cannot inflate another layout, this should do the trick.

Comment: @invariant What if a layout(view) has a button and other doesn't, assuming that the button has OnClick event implemented?

Comment: what if I had an unknown number of views to add?

Comment: @CQM then you need your itemView to be another n-views container such as ListView, could be another RecyclerView, any implementation of AdapterView or any custom view that's capable of holding variable amount of views, basically a 'nested list view' problem

Comment: Saved the day. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can also set `itemView.setHasTransientState(true)` in which case the view will not be recycled until `setHasTransientState` is set to `false`.

Answer (score 2):

With help from @grgrssll's answer I was able to fix my problem. In my case I needed N-number of TextViews inside each row.

In my **onBindViewHolder**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final HistoryViewHolder vh, int position) {
    ...
    //Generating N-number of TextViews depending on size of itemsMap
    for (Map.Entry<String, Model> entry : itemsMap.entrySet()) {
        SelectedModel s = entry.getValue();
        // Set setHasTransientState to true
        vh.itemDetailsContainer.setHasTransientState(true);    
        // Dynamically adding the views
        vh.itemDetailsContainer.addView(getItemTextView(context, s.getItemName()));
        ...
    }
    //Set setHasTranssientState to false after loop
    vh.itemDetailsContainer.setHasTransientState(false);
    ...
}
```

Comment: can please help how to add n number of text view inside a row

Comment: @karthik What I have done in my code is, that in my onBindViewHolder, I have a HashMap (or it can be an array) of some items. For each item in my loop i create a TextView (getItemTextView just creates a new TextView) and then I add it to my container (row).