# Recyclerview index position mess data on scrolling of recycler

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

First time data populate proper. But when I scroll `recyclerview` from bottom to top all data and its position messed. I tried adding 
`itemViewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);` 
`setHasStableIds(false)` but nothing works 
Inside vertical recyclerview trying to populate horizontal recyclerview

```
public HomeRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, Home homeModel) {
        this.context = context;
        this.homeModel = homeModel;
    }
 @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.homefragment_header, parent, false);
            return new HeaderViewHolder(v);
        } else if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_homefragment, parent, false);
            return new ItemViewHolder(v);
        } else if (viewType == PRODUCT_ITEM) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_productlines, parent, false);
            return new ProductLinesItemHolder(v);
        } else if (viewType == SHOPS_ITEM) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_productlines, parent, false);
            return new ShopsOfWeekItemHolder(v);
        }
        return null;
    } 
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            if (holder instanceof HeaderViewHolder) {
              // load data in slider
            }
        } else if (holder instanceof ItemViewHolder) {
            ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
            if (homeModel.getCategories().get(0) != null) {
                if (position == 1) {
                     //load data in category recyclerview
                    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
                }
            }
        } else if (holder instanceof ProductLinesItemHolder) {
            ProductLinesItemHolder itemViewHolder = (ProductLinesItemHolder) holder;
            if (homeModel.getProductLines() != null) {
                if (position > 1 && pos <= homeModel.getProductLines().size()-1) {
                    Log.d("HomeRecycler","pos:"+pos);
                    Log.d("HomeRecycler","position:"+ (position-2));
                        setRecyclerView(2, itemViewHolder);
                        Log.d("HomeRecycler","pos:"+homeModel.getProductLines().get(pos).getName());
                        itemViewHolder.txtProductName.setText(homeModel.getProductLines().get(pos).getName());
                        itemViewHolder.txtViewAllShops.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        populateProductLinesItem(itemViewHolder, homeModel.getProductLines().get(pos));
                        pos = pos + 1;

                }
            }
        }
private void populateProductLinesItem(ProductLinesItemHolder itemViewHolder, ProductLines productLines) {
        ProductLinesItemAdapter productLinesItemAdapter = new ProductLinesItemAdapter(context, productLines.getItems(), clickEventOfProductsItemListener);
        itemViewHolder.prodLinesRecyclerView.setAdapter(productLinesItemAdapter);
        productLinesItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Can someone pls suggest?? how to avoid this issue ? 
More code : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7785cdd97b5c27886c81f321c8965930

Answer (score 0):

Based on this:

> But when I scroll recyclerview from bottom to top all data and its position messed.

There was a similar problem and here's the [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552070/dynamically-adding-views-in-a-recyclerview-only-to-current-item/42482524#42482524) for it!