# How to add custom view inside RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

I have a RecyclerView and successfully adapted some data. I have a problem. In the onBindViewHolder method, I am trying to add a custom view in a linear layout. The custom view is successfully added, but in scroll up or down views are duplicated. I want to add only once with items.

My code:

```
public class TrainsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public ArrayList<Train> trains;
    public Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

    public void setmOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener) {
        this.mOnItemClickListener = mOnItemClickListener;
    }


    public class GenericViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView stationName;
        public LinearLayout vagoncontainer;

        public GenericViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            stationName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.station_item_name);
            vagoncontainer = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.vagon_container);


        }
    }

    public TrainsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Train> trains) {
        this.context = context;
        this.trains = trains;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);


    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trains_adapter_item, parent, false);
        GenericViewHolder holder = new GenericViewHolder(view);
        return holder;


    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (holder instanceof GenericViewHolder) {
            GenericViewHolder genericViewHolder = (GenericViewHolder) holder;
            Train train = trains.get(position);
            ArrayList<Vagons> vagons = train.getVagons();
            for (int i = 0; i < vagons.size(); i++) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                LinearLayout vagonView = (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.trains_vagon_child, null);
                Button button = (Button) vagonView.findViewById(R.id.button);
                if (vagons.get(i).getEnable().equals("1"))
                    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                else
                    button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                button.setText(vagons.get(i).getName() + " " + vagons.get(i).getAmount());
                genericViewHolder.vagoncontainer.addView(vagonView);
            }


            genericViewHolder.stationName.setText(train.getDeparture());

        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return trains.size();
    }

    public Train getItem(int position) {
        return trains.get(position);
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Why are you using loop inside onBindViewHolder ? Try removing that.

Comment: because  in my main data contains some Vagon's data and i want to add them by position @ tahsinRupam

Comment: Do you want to make an expandable RecyclerView, with Train class as parent and Vagon class as child?

Comment: Since  you want to inflate the layout only one time why don't you just added as a static layout instead of adding it to the list ?

Answer (score 1):

This will fix your problem, but it is not effective (it won't be scrolling smoothly for trains with large amount of vagons - inflating Views is expensive), since you will be removing and recreating views in that `LinearLayout` representing row in `ListView`. Either reconsider your row layout or create some pseudo recyling in your row view.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (holder instanceof GenericViewHolder) {
        GenericViewHolder genericViewHolder = (GenericViewHolder) holder;
        genericViewHolder.vagoncontainer.removeAllViews();
        Train train = trains.get(position);
        ArrayList<Vagons> vagons = train.getVagons();
        for (int i = 0; i < vagons.size(); i++) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            LinearLayout vagonView = (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.trains_vagon_child, null);
            Button button = (Button) vagonView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            if (vagons.get(i).getEnable().equals("1"))
                button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
                button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            button.setText(vagons.get(i).getName() + " " + vagons.get(i).getAmount());
            genericViewHolder.vagoncontainer.addView(vagonView);
        }

        genericViewHolder.stationName.setText(train.getDeparture());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [core adapter](https://github.com/sajadshokri/Core-Adapter)

It's a simple lib to Support Any Type of items in recyclerview with no pain.

Answer (score 0):

Basically RecyclerView reuses your viewHolder. So as per the RecyclerView doc [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) You have to reset the views everytime inside the `onBindViewHolder()` method,

And based on this

> but in scroll up or down views are dublicated.I want to add only one time with items

you need to `removeAllViews` inside your `vagonContainer` viewgroup

so your bind holder will look like

```
if (holder instanceof GenericViewHolder) {
        GenericViewHolder genericViewHolder = (GenericViewHolder) holder;
        Train train = trains.get(position);
        ArrayList<Vagons> vagons = train.getVagons();

        // this is very important. removing all view
        genericViewHolder.vagoncontainer.removeAllViews();
......
```

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552070/dynamically-adding-views-in-a-recyclerview-only-to-current-item/42482524#42482524)