# How do I create a RecyclerView adapter for a list within a list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am building a recipe app (static data).

I've created a class "Recipes", and inside a singleton object, I've created a list of Recipe instances.

The Recipes class holds the following parameters:

```
title: String
ingredients: List<String>
instructions : String
time: Long serves:
Int cost: String
source : String
```

Now I want to create an adapter for ingredients, so I can create a `RecyclerView` for the list of ingredients.

My problem is passing to the adapter the List of the ingredients, as opposed to the list of recipes.

I am trying different things but not quite sure what to do. Been stuck with that issue for a few days already.

This is the Recipes class:

```
class Recipes(val title: String, val ingredients: List<String>, val instructions: String, val time: Long, val serves: Int, val level: String, val source: String) {

    private val prepTimeHours: Long = time / 60
    private val preTimeMinutes: Long = time.rem(60)
    val prepTime: String = "${prepTimeHours.toString()}:${preTimeMinutes.toString()}"

    val peopleServed: String = "$serves adults"
}
```

This is the Singleton:

```
object AllRecipes {

    val recipeBook = listOf(
        Recipes ("Red wine-braised baby octopus with black olives", listOf("vegetables", "fruits", "candy"), "cook like this make like that", 90, 6, "easy", "https://www.foodandwine.com/recipes/red-wine-braised-baby-octopus-with-black-olives"),
        Recipes ("2Red wine-braised baby octopus with black olives", listOf("vegetables", "fruits", "candy"), "cook like this make like that", 90, 6, "easy", "https://www.foodandwine.com/recipes/red-wine-braised-baby-octopus-with-black-olives"),
        Recipes ("3Red wine-braised baby octopus with black olives", listOf("vegetables", "fruits", "candy"), "cook like this make like that", 90, 6, "easy", "https://www.foodandwine.com/recipes/red-wine-braised-baby-octopus-with-black-olives"),
        Recipes ("4Red wine-braised baby octopus with black olives", listOf("vegetables", "fruits", "candy"), "cook like this make like that", 90, 6, "easy", "https://www.foodandwine.com/recipes/red-wine-braised-baby-octopus-with-black-olives"),
        Recipes ("5Red wine-braised baby octopus with black olives", listOf("vegetables", "fruits", "candy"), "cook like this make like that", 90, 6, "easy", "https://www.foodandwine.com/recipes/red-wine-braised-baby-octopus-with-black-olives"),
        Recipes ("6Red wine-braised baby octopus with black olives", listOf("vegetables", "fruits", "candy"), "cook like this make like that", 90, 6, "easy", "https://www.foodandwine.com/recipes/red-wine-braised-baby-octopus-with-black-olives"),
        Recipes ("7Red wine-braised baby octopus with black olives", listOf("vegetables", "fruits", "candy"), "cook like this make like that", 90, 6, "easy", "https://www.foodandwine.com/recipes/red-wine-braised-baby-octopus-with-black-olives"),
        Recipes ("8Red wine-braised baby octopus with black olives", listOf("vegetables", "fruits", "candy"), "cook like this make like that", 90, 6, "easy", "https://www.foodandwine.com/recipes/red-wine-braised-baby-octopus-with-black-olives"))
}
```

This is my current adapter:

```
class IngredientsAdapter(val context: Context, val ingredient: List<Recipes>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<IngredientsAdapter.Holder>() {

    inner class Holder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val singleIngredient = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.single_ingredient)

        fun bindText(textVar: Recipes, context: Context) {
            singleIngredient.text = textVar.ingredients[adapterPosition]
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindText(ingredient[position], context)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return ingredient.count()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Holder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.ingredients_layout, parent, false)
        return Holder(view)
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32332381/3145960). The key idea is to add extra views with each item of your `RecyclerView` for each of your ingredients. You do not have to implement a nested `RecyclerView` actually for your case. Just adding more layouts to each item should be fine as the ingredients are limited.

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32333608/3145960) shows three different ways. If your ingredients are not that large in number, you can have multiple `TextView`s along with each item of your main `RecyclerView` as well with a default visibility with `View.GONE`. Where based on how many ingredients you have, you might consider enabling the visibility of some while the other still remains invisible.

Hope that helps!